# Yii2 Form view component other database

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, model-view-controller, yii2

I have a modules named BillingPayment
the main `Yii2` Project use db1 database which is a `PostgreSQL` for login and other modules.

Inside the BillingPayment Form there is a Select Option which is need to grab data (record) from other database 'db2' which is `MySQL` database

Is there a way to select the record into select option beside using multiple database connection?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the connection somewhere but you can do it in the very last step like:

```
$record = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select($columns)
    ->from($tableInSecondDatabase)
    ->where($conditions)
    ->one(\Yii::createObject([
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=x.x.x.x;dbname=db2',
        'username' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ]));
```

Now you can use the data from `$record` to populate the dropdown list.